# change width of @Html.DropDownListFor dynamically based on the length of text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

We all know that this works.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProvisionalAward, Model.PreviousProvisionalAwardDecisions, new { style = "width: 250px;" })
```

But how do we make the something like this

```
   @{var width = @Model.PreviousProvisionalAwardDecisions.FirstOrDefault().Text.Length; }
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProvisionalAward, Model.PreviousProvisionalAwardDecisions, new { style = "width:"+ @width + "px;" })
```

What I want to achieve is width of the dropdown list  extended to fill the full text displayed inside it. The obvious problem with this is that the length variable for a text with 42 symbols will output 42 but the width required to display that will be probably around 260px. Please assume that all items in the select list have the same length.

Comment: What if first option will contain 10 symbols and second - 100500 symbols?

Comment: good point but in my case they are all the same length. dont ask me why its a legacy system

Comment: How about resizing it dynamically through client-side code? Personally I will check length of the value in `<select>` element and then use CSS manipulation from JS to resize those elements.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto can you provide some codepen prove of concept please ?